# HSQLDB in file mode is not saved?

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm running a HSQLDB in file mode.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/MyDB" />
```

But I cannot find this database file in `user.home` nor anywhere else on my computer.

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(obj);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I can see the objects in my application are persisted. If I reload my app in the browser, the objects are still there. But if I redeploy my app with

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

the database is empty.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I was missing `em.close();` here. This way all my data gets saved in the `MyDB.script` file.

Comment: there is no "close" on the getTransaction()

Comment: I probably meant em.close(), but mate this question is 1,5 yrs ago, sorry can't remember the solution exactly.